# ObjectDisposedException when trying to call a task (fire and forget) inside controller and change state of entity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

i have a .netcore webAPI controller, one of his functionalities is to upload files..

so when user uploads a file, a task is lunched to call AI webservice.

Based on the results of the webservice, some changes will be applied on the entity.

```
 [HttpPost("upload/{id}")]
 public async Task<string> UploadFile(int id)
 {
     //upload file
     Task.Run(() => callForAI(id,names,pathExported));
     return "ok";
 }
 public async Task callForAI(int id,List<string>names,string path)
 {
     User user= await _context.User.FindAsync(id);//here comes the exception
     //some changes to make
     _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

by doing so, an exception rizes:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll

Comment: Fire-and-forget is rarely a good idea. Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `async/await` is wrong here. There's no need to call `callForAI` on a new thread. Running it on a separate thread means there's a high likelihood that `UpLoadFile` will return before the thread completes, and at this point the context is being destroyed.

Try rewriting it like this:

```
 [HttpPost("upload/{id}")]
 public async Task<string> UploadFile(int id)
 {
     //upload file
     await callForAI(id, names, pathExported);
     return "ok";
 }
 public async Task callForAI(int id, List<string>names, string path)
 {
     User user= await _context.User.FindAsync(id);
     //some changes to make
     _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

Also, you had flagged `UploadFile` as an `async` method, but you were not `await`ing anything, so you should have seen a compiler warning telling you this. When you get these warnings it's a clear sign that you are doing `async/await` wrong.

Comment: It seems that the OP wants to run this as fire-and-forget, so the HTTP response is sent before the database is updated.

Comment: yeah, @sean you're somhow right. but i wanted to fire the AI task in background and return a response for the file upload

Answer (score 0):

"Fire and forget" is almost never the correct solution. "Fire and forget" means:

1. You don't care if the additional code has an exception.
2. You don't care if the additional code completes.
3. You don't care if the additional code even runs.

The use cases for "fire and forget" are incredibly small. Essentially it's only useful for things like "update this distributed cache entry", where it doesn't really make a lot of difference whether the operation is even done or not. Using a database in your additional work is a strong indicator that "fire and forget" is an incorrect solution for your problem.

If you don't want the user to have to wait for the operation to complete, a more proper design is to have your action save the work to a persistent queue, and then have a separate background worker read from that queue and do the actual work.

However, if you insist on using the problematic "fire and forget" pattern, then you would just need to keep in mind that "fire and forget" work is executed outside of a request context. So anything that's injected into your controller with a scoped lifetime cannot be used. Your code would need to create its own db context.